# A regex for Matching I.text in c#

Tags: c#, regex, roman-numerals

I'm trying to parse a PDF to XML in c# and i want to extract headings like: I. INTRODUCTION, II. PAGE LAYOUT which are categorized by roman numerals from my file. I would like to write a regex to match strings like this I tried a couple of things but doesn't work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

[IVXLCDM]+. [A-Z ]+

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx):

> \. will match a period since the period character is a special character (meaning match any character) in regular expression syntax.

On the other hand, if you want to make sure that the string contains only Roman numerals and a heading name, you might want to use this:

```
^[IVXLCDM]+\. [A-Z ]+$
```

The `^` and `$` are called anchors. The `^` instructs the regex engine to start matching from the very beginning of the string while the `$` instructs the regex engine to stop matching at the very end of the string.
The complete list of Roman Numerals can be obtained from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple one

> \b[IVX]+. [A-Z ]+

Answer (score 1):

This should mostly work:

```
^[IVXLCDM]+\. [^\p{Ll}]+?$
```

This will match headers containing numbers and symbols, but will explicitly exclude Unicode lowercase characters.

Also, ensure that you use the option RegexOptions.Multiline, like so: (where `inp` is your input string)

```
foreach (var match in
    Regex.Matches(inp,
        @"^[IVXLCDM]+\. [^\p{Ll}]+?$",
        RegexOptions.Multiline))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```